The consumer isn't authorized to access %resources. Magento 2.4.7 & 2.4.7-p3
The consumer isn't authorized to access %resources.
{
"message": "The consumer isn't authorized to access %resources.",
"parameters": {
    "resources": "Magento_Catalog::products"
}

Trace Error
"trace": "#0 /vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/RequestValidator.php(92): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\RequestValidator->checkPermissions(Object(Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Router\\Route\\Interceptor))

Refer snap for more clarity which we integrate points set with all resources and set all fines still facing the same error.
Note:
I've recently installed Magento 2.4.7 on our staging server (using cPanel), and we’re encountering several issues. No third-party extensions or themes are installed, and the installation works fine locally on Docker. However, the staging environment is giving us trouble.
Here’s what we’ve tried so far:

Adjusting the .htaccess file.
Changing directory permissions for the
vendor folder. Updating to the latest patch (Magento 2.4.7-p3).

Despite these efforts, the issues persist. Has anyone else encountered similar problems, or could you suggest any troubleshooting steps for a fresh Magento installation in a cPanel environment?
Thank you in advance for any insights or recommendations!
Integration Points set

**Administrators Role with All **

Web Api settings

Bearer settings

